# Redirect в .htaccess или проблема из картинками

Tags: php, сервер, backend, php-nginx

Есть сайт с такими вот правилами редиректа:

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule \.(css|js|png|jpg|gif)$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(index\.php|robots\.txt)$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Все хорошо, но столкнулся с проблемой отображения изображений:
Структура каталогов: <корень>/Users/backgrounds/<Тут фотки>

Таким образом я пытаюсь достать их:

```
$directory = '/Users/backgrounds'; 
if ($handle = opendir($directory)) {
            while (false !==($file = readdir($handle)))    //поиск по файлам
            {//тут последующий код }
    }
closedir($handle);
```

И у меня выскакивает сообщение:

> Warning: opendir(/Users/backgrounds): failed to open dir: No such file
>   or directory in...

Comment: Ну вам явно в ошибке написали, что папка не найдена. Попробуйте использовать абсолютный путь

Answer (score 0):

Проблема вот в чем:
Так нужно определять директорию для рабаты серверной части:

```
 $directory =realpath(__DIR__ . '/../Users/backgrounds');
```

А так для ХТМЛ

```
/Users/backgrounds/
```

Тема закрыта :)